# How to stop pandoc from escaping characters?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Suppose I want to use pandoc to convert between markdown flavors:

```sh
$ echo "# Header #1" | pandoc -t markdown
```

I get the following output with the `#1` escaped:

```
Header \#1
==========
```

How do I prevent pandoc from doing this?

Comment: hm.. I think that's currently a limitation of pandoc... i does a little bit more escaping than necessary.. but you can file a feature request over at github... or ask on pandoc-discuss..

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: Filed https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6259

Comment: you can also try `-t commonmark`...

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to `sed` like this to remove `\`

```sh
$ echo "# Header #1" | pandoc -t markdown | sed 's/\\//g'
```

I know this is not a perfect solution, but it works if your document does not contain `\` char.